# How to execute raw query with union operator in EF Core?

Tags: c#, mysql, nopcommerce

I have two tables in my database. One is **equipmentassignment** and another is **equipmenttransfer**

**equipmentassignment**

[image]
Data of this table 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FctUY.png)

**equipmenttransfer**

[image]
Data of this table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW0PA.png)

I am able to get all data from both tables using union operator in mysql using below query

```
SELECT id, 
       status, 
       deleted, 
       propertyid, 
       premiseid, 
       equipmentid, 
       assigntimeutc, 
       deassigntimeutc 
FROM   equipmenttransfer 
WHERE ! deleted 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 
       status, 
       deleted, 
       propertyid, 
       premiseid, 
       equipmentid, 
       assigntimeutc, 
       Cast('0001-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME(6)) AS deassigntimeutc 
FROM   equipmentassignment 
WHERE ! deleted;
```

Here is the snapshot of my query

[image]

The query is working fine in MySql workbench but when I use the same query in ef core it gives me wrong result. Code is below:

```
string query="select id,status,deleted,propertyid,premiseid,equipmentid,assigntimeutc,deassigntimeutc from equipmenttransfer where !Deleted "+
                     "union all select id, status,deleted, propertyid, premiseid, equipmentid, assigntimeutc, cast('0001-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime(6)) as deassigntimeutc from equipmentassignment where !Deleted"
var result =  _context.EntityListFromSql<EquipmentTransfer>(query);//_context dependency is resolved
```

//Calling function of DbContext

```
public IList<TEntity> EntityListFromSql<TEntity>(string sql) where TEntity : BaseEntity
        {
            return base.Set<TEntity>().FromSql(sql).ToList();
        }
```

When I run this I get data but equipmentassignment row is replaced by equipmenttransfer row having same ID

Result in json:

> "data": [
>       {
>         "Status": "Unassigned",
>         "AssignTimeUTC": "2019-10-22T18:41:38.484896",
>         "DeAssignTimeUTC": "2019-10-22T18:57:02.413901",
>         "PropertyId": 1,
>         "PropertyName": "MT",
>         "PremiseId": 1,
>         "PremiseName": "Test",
>         "EquipmentId": 1,
>         "EquipmentName": "Test",
>         "Id": 1
>       },
>       {
>         "Status": "Unassigned",
>         "AssignTimeUTC": "2019-10-22T18:57:02.389344",
>         "DeAssignTimeUTC": "2019-10-22T18:57:11.947434",
>         "PropertyId": 1,
>         "PropertyName": "MT",
>         "PremiseId": 1,
>         "PremiseName": "Test",
>         "EquipmentId": 1,
>         "EquipmentName": "Test",
>         "Id": 2
>       },
>       {
>         "Status": "Unassigned",
>         "AssignTimeUTC": "2019-10-22T18:57:11.936514",
>         "DeAssignTimeUTC": "2019-10-22T20:21:51.272807",
>         "PropertyId": 1,
>         "PropertyName": "MT",
>         "PremiseId": 1,
>         "PremiseName": "Test",
>         "EquipmentId": 1,
>         "EquipmentName": "Test",
>         "Id": 3
>       },
>       {
>         "Status": "Unassigned",
>         "AssignTimeUTC": "2019-10-22T20:21:51.214298",
>         "DeAssignTimeUTC": "2019-10-22T20:21:57.397432",
>         "PropertyId": 1,
>         "PropertyName": "MT",
>         "PremiseId": 1,
>         "PremiseName": "Test",
>         "EquipmentId": 1,
>         "EquipmentName": "Test",
>         "Id": 4
>       },
>       {
>         "Status": "Unassigned",
>         "AssignTimeUTC": "2019-10-22T18:41:38.484896",
>         "DeAssignTimeUTC": "2019-10-22T18:57:02.413901",
>         "PropertyId": 1,
>         "PropertyName": "MT",
>         "PremiseId": 1,
>         "PremiseName": "Test",
>         "EquipmentId": 1,
>         "EquipmentName": "Test",
>         "Id": 1
>       }   ]

It seems that ef core doesn't retrieve the result as mysql workbench does. What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tryed `WHERE deleted <> 0` instead?

Comment: please run a `EXPLAIN SELECT id, 
       status, 
       deleted, 
       propertyid, 
       premiseid, 
       equipmentid, 
       assigntimeutc, 
       deassigntimeutc 
FROM   equipmenttransfer 
WHERE ! deleted 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 
       status, 
       deleted, 
       propertyid, 
       premiseid, 
       equipmentid, 
       assigntimeutc, 
       Cast('0001-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME(6)) AS deassigntimeutc 
FROM   equipmentassignment 
WHERE ! deleted; SHOW WARNINGS;`  and copy paste..

Comment: it feels like `WHERE ! deleted ` executes as `WHERE 1`

Comment: I want those data which is not deleted that's why i use !deleted 
Fact is my query is running fine in MySql IDE but efcore does not give the proper result

Comment: You can see the result snapshot I attached is okay. But the result from ef core is not ok.

Comment: You are querying the  equipmenttransfer (not the equipmentassignment) : var result =  _context.EntityListFromSql<EquipmentTransfer>(query);

Comment: yeah that's right but here in my query I project my data from equipmentassignment with union all so that I can get data from both of my table